# add dynamic button click event c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

with json data, created a table with for loop and added dynamic buttons in different conditions, am looking how to add one onclick event for all buttons and get the value of clicked button value or id.

Thank you for your help

```
dynamic jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsondata.val.Count; i++)
        {
           htmlTable.AppendLine("<tr>");
           htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>"+jsondata.val[i].id+"</td>");
           htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>"+jsondata.val[i].Name+"</td>");
           htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>"+jsondata.val[i].desc+"</td>");
    
            string getStatus = GetStatus(url);
            if(getStatus=="0")
                  htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>" + "<input id='ctb"+i+ "' type='button' value='START'></td>");
            else if(getStatus=="1")
                   htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>" +"<input id='ctb"+i+ "' type='button' value='STOP'></td>");
            else
                   htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>" + "<label> Error Occured </label></td>");
    
            htmlTable.AppendLine("</tr>");
          }
     htmlTable.AppendLine("</table>");
     litTable.Text = htmlTable.ToString();
```

Comment: It's better to deserialize the json to c# class collection and bind it to a datagrid. You can add buttons to datagrid columns and attach events to it much easier than creating html at run time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple demo, But you can do the same in your scenario as well. I just implemented this sample in WebForm. If I am mistaken do comment please.

```
public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            divContainer.InnerHtml = "<div id='mysamplecontrol' onclick='thisismyclick(this);'>Start</div>";
        }
    }
```

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div runat="server" id="divContainer"></div>
        <script>
            function thisismyclick(control) {
                alert(control.id);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```